# Flutter: I get an error when trying to output TabBarView "RenderBox was not laid out: RenderFlex#dc538 ..."

Tags: flutter

When I try to output TabBarView and expand it over a possible area of the screen using Expanded, I get an error "RenderBox was not laid out: RenderFlex#dc538 relayoutBoundary=up16 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE

'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':

Failed assertion: line 1966 pos 12: 'hasSize'".

I've also tried using Flexible and FlexFit.loose but to no avail

Can you tell me how I can get the result I need?

profile.dart

```
// ignore_for_file: prefer_typing_uninitialized_variables

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';
import 'package:resourse_app/features/auth/bloc/auth_bloc.dart';
import 'package:resourse_app/features/profile/widget/free_content.dart';
import 'package:resourse_app/features/profile/widget/paid_content.dart';
import 'package:resourse_app/features/profile/widget/side_bar.dart';
import 'package:resourse_app/features/wallet/view/wallet_screen.dart';
import '../../../repositories/models/users/user.dart';
import '../../../repositories/user/user_repositories.dart';
import '../../../theme/style_for_text.dart';
import '../../auth/widgets/button_for_auth_screen.dart';
import '../widget/choice_content.dart';
import '../widget/descriptions_for_profile.dart';
import '../widget/user_image.dart';

class ProfileScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  static const String id = 'profile_screen';

  const ProfileScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<ProfileScreen> createState() => _ProfileScreenState();
}

class _ProfileScreenState extends State<ProfileScreen>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();

  UserAccount? _user;

  Future<UserAccount> _loadUser() async {
    _user = await UserRepositories().getUserData();
    setState(() {});
    return _user!;
  }

  late final _authBloc;
  late TabController _tabController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _tabController = TabController(length: 2, vsync: this);
    _tabController.addListener(() {
      setState(() {});
    });
    _loadUser();
    _authBloc = context.read<AuthBloc>();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _tabController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final theme = Theme.of(context).textTheme;
    double wh = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    double hh = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;

    return SafeArea(
      child: _user == null
          ? const Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
            )
          : Scaffold(
              key: _scaffoldKey,
              appBar: AppBar(
                title: const Text('username'),
                actions: [
                  //add post
                  IconButton(
                    onPressed: () {},
                    icon: const Icon(Icons.add_sharp),
                  ),
                  //wallet
                  IconButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      Navigator.push(
                        context,
                        MaterialPageRoute(
                          builder: (context) => const WalletScreen(),
                        ),
                      );
                    },
                    icon: const Icon(Icons.account_balance_wallet),
                  ),
                  //menu
                  IconButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      _scaffoldKey.currentState!.openEndDrawer();
                    },
                    icon: const Icon(Icons.menu),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              body: Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                    horizontal: wh * 0.04, vertical: hh * 0.02),
                child: ListView(
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
                  children: <Widget>[
                    FutureBuilder(
                        future: _loadUser(),
                        builder: (context, snapshot) {
                          return Row(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                            children: <Widget>[
                              UserImage(
                                imageUrl: snapshot.data?.avatarUrl ?? '',
                              ),
                              SizedBox(
                                width: wh * 0.20,
                              ),
                              DescriptionsForProfile(
                                name: snapshot.data?.name ?? '',
                                phone: snapshot.data?.phone ?? '',
                                description: snapshot.data?.description ?? '',
                                mail: snapshot.data?.mail ?? '',
                              ),
                            ],
                          );
                        }),
                    const SizedBox(
                      height: 30,
                    ),
                    ChoiceContent(controller: _tabController,),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              endDrawer: SideBar(theme: theme, authBloc: _authBloc)),
    );
  }
}
```

choice_content.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:resourse_app/features/profile/widget/paid_content.dart';

import 'free_content.dart';

class ChoiceContent extends StatelessWidget {
  final TabController controller;
  const ChoiceContent({Key? key, required this.controller}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double wh = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;

    return Column(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(
          width: wh,
          height: 40,
          child: TabBar(
            controller: controller,
            tabs: const [
              Tab(
                text: 'Платный контент',
              ),
              Tab(
                text: 'Бесплатный контент',
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        Flexible(
          fit: FlexFit.loose,
          child: TabBarView(
            controller: controller,
            children: const [
              PaidContent(),
              FreeContent(),
            ],
          ),
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

free_content.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class FreeContent extends StatelessWidget {
  const FreeContent({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Text('Бесплатный контент'),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

paid_content.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class FreeContent extends StatelessWidget {
  const FreeContent({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Text('Платный контент'),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Simply wrap your `ChoiceContent` widget with `Expanded`

- ##### This will allow your `ChoiceContent` widget to take up the remaining space in the ListView and prevents the `"Render box was not laid out"` error.
- ##### Update your profile widget like so

```dart
class ProfileScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  static const String id = 'profile_screen';

  const ProfileScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<ProfileScreen> createState() => _ProfileScreenState();
}

class _ProfileScreenState extends State<ProfileScreen>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();

  UserAccount? _user;

  Future<UserAccount> _loadUser() async {
    _user = await UserRepositories().getUserData();
    setState(() {});
    return _user!;
  }

  late final _authBloc;
  late TabController _tabController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _tabController = TabController(length: 2, vsync: this);
    _tabController.addListener(() {
      setState(() {});
    });
    _loadUser();
    _authBloc = context.read<AuthBloc>();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _tabController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final theme = Theme.of(context).textTheme;
    double wh = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    double hh = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;

    return SafeArea(
      child: _user == null
          ? const Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
            )
          : Scaffold(
              key: _scaffoldKey,
              appBar: AppBar(
                title: const Text('username'),
                actions: [
                  //add post
                  IconButton(
                    onPressed: () {},
                    icon: const Icon(Icons.add_sharp),
                  ),
                  //wallet
                  IconButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      Navigator.push(
                        context,
                        MaterialPageRoute(
                          builder: (context) => const WalletScreen(),
                        ),
                      );
                    },
                    icon: const Icon(Icons.account_balance_wallet),
                  ),
                  //menu
                  IconButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      _scaffoldKey.currentState!.openEndDrawer();
                    },
                    icon: const Icon(Icons.menu),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              body: Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                    horizontal: wh * 0.04, vertical: hh * 0.02),
                child: ListView(
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
                  children: <Widget>[
                    FutureBuilder(
                      future: _loadUser(),
                      builder: (context, snapshot) {
                        return Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            UserImage(
                              imageUrl: snapshot.data?.avatarUrl ?? '',
                            ),
                            SizedBox(
                              width: wh * 0.20,
                            ),
                            DescriptionsForProfile(
                              name: snapshot.data?.name ?? '',
                              phone: snapshot.data?.phone ?? '',
                              description: snapshot.data?.description ?? '',
                              mail: snapshot.data?.mail ?? '',
                            ),
                          ],
                        );
                      },
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(
                      height: 30,
                    ),
                    Expanded(
                      child: ChoiceContent(controller: _tabController),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              endDrawer: SideBar(theme: theme, authBloc: _authBloc),
            ),
    );
  }
}
```

#### Happy coding

Comment: Unfortunately I still get the same error